# Trajectory opimization: fast preview algorithm

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacecraft, trajectory

I have been interested in trajectory optimization for a while now and I have read a few papers on that topic and bought the book "Spacecraft trajectory optimization" from Cambridge University Press and want to start programming with the goal to optimize a trajectory in a simplified solar system, not in real time but as close as possible, without the need of an exact solution but a preview of a good one.

The books and papers propose different approaches like

- Analytical solutions with the primer vector
- Direct transcription + nonlinear programming
- particle swarm algorithms
- evolutionary/genetic algorithms

because I have little to no experience I would like to know what you guys would suggest because I could not find any comparisons with regard to speed of these algorithms.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a very broad question. You admitted it yourself; you bought a book and looked at  journal articles to understand the topic.

Comment: My question was not meant that way. Because I am new to this topic I asked for some advice to point me in the right direction otherwise I would need to try all these approaches myself - understanding the topic will take more time I am willing to invest.

Comment: @user2487105 Our [About] and [Ask] pages explain that we're a Q&A (questions and answers) site and not a discussion forum, so questions need to be specific, not solicit prolonged discussion, and have a definitive answer that, ideally, would be of reasonable length. Your question is both too broad, as well as primarily opinion based, and as such not suitable for our Q&A. But you're welcome to join us in our [chat], where open discussion (like the one you continue in your comments to the answer) is acceptable and asking for opinions (which will differ) isn't discouraged. Thanks!

Comment: I can not join the chat - I need 20 reputation. Still: Thank you.

Comment: Don't code up something yourself. Get a trajectory optimization program like [OTIS](http://otis.grc.nasa.gov/request.html) or [POST](http://post2.larc.nasa.gov). Note both probably require you to be a US Person, as they are export controlled software.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some quick pieces of information based on my experience coding / researching each of these areas:

- Primer vector: The primer vector has a fairly elegant solution once you find the Hamiltonian and other required variables in the algorithm (e.g., the adjoints). Once you're able to set up the problem, the solution tends to fall out fairly well. Most of the applications I've seen with primer vector are part of the 'optimal transfer' problem.
- Nonlinear programming: NLP can be fairly cumbersome and difficult to code and you often end up coding a lot of constraints. BUT - of the four you mentioned, past literature reviews have shown NLP gives the best results. Conway gives some great examples that may or may not be in that text, but examine his pursuit/evasion works and the NLP generated trajectories.
- Particle swarm: PSO is one of my favorite algorithms to implement. Showalter and Black [1] recently used PSO to generate responsive theater maneuvers (This work actually includes a PSO within a PSO). With regard to orbital transfers, you'll find a lot of the time spent inside a PSO will be propagating your trajectory. You can simplify this using Keplerian motion, but full-up numerical integration with higher-order perturbations will increase your computation time.
- Genetic algorithms: GA's can be *very* computationally expensive based on whether you are doing single-objective or multi-objective optimization, your design variables, your constraints, and so forth. Moreover, GA's also depend on your minimum number of generations generated. There are a lot of variants on the GA, but the computation time of a GA is, one can argue, user dependent.

Side notes:

- These algorithms will also depend on how complex your cost function is, and your convergence criteria.
- Computation time will be a function of your model's fidelity

Finally, when you consider NLP as a higher-fidelity algorithm, the question becomes 'what is my initial guess?' to feed the NLP (since your convergence in a numerical algorithm is often based on how close you are to an answer). You can use PSO or primer vector or any number/combination of optimization routines as a warm-up / initial guess to NLP or higher fidelity model that will place you in the neighborhood of a, hopefully, good solution.

1: http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/1.A32989

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Some of your points were mentioned in what I have read so far as well but that is only a partial answer to my question; from what you have said GA's are pretty good to find global minima of the cost function even with a bad first guess but are pretty slow. I am looking for a solution that is as fast as possible but where finding the global minima is not required - a 'good' solution is fine. So I am still unsure of which approach to take; as mentioned before it should be consider a preview.

Comment: You suggested that PSO could be used as a preprocessor because they create a good guess but converge slowly towards the optimal solution. I know these questions a pretty general and thus difficult to answer but take our solar system as an example: If I wanted to calculate an interplanetary transfer from, let's say Earth to Jupiter, take all planets and the sun into consideration and limit the transition time to a year would it be possible to calculate the necessary manoeuvres within a minute? Again, please excuse these kind of questions but I am pretty inexperienced in that field.